# ArcGIS do calcuation on multiple input fields of attribute table and the number of input fields is changing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have attribute table with headers: 
**ID(bgrp), F1 (F2011_46), F2 (F2011_48), ...Fn**

[image]

I want to do math calculations on the fields from F1 to Fn. For example, count the total number of non-zero Fn fields for each ID unit. Normally, a field calculator using python script will do the job. But the problem is **n vary each time** and I have **many such tables**, so I don't know if I should modify the input fields each time when do field calculation for one such table. Additionally, **n is usually large**, 30 to 100, and I don't think it is efficient to manually select all the Fn fields in a Pre-Logic Script Code.

Comment: I take it that it's ArcGis? You should probably include a tag or reference in your question indicating the software. This is probably not something you want to do in Field Calculator but if you persist then you could *conceivably* use ListFields to get the fields... what field type in particular? Do you want all the numeric, double, text..?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer, but it's a bit hacky... halfway between Field Calculator and true arcpy tool:

```
def CalcThis(YourID):
    YourFeatClassOrLayerName = "Polylines" # Change this to your layer name
    desc = arcpy.Describe(YourFeatClassOrLayerName)

    fList = arcpy.ListFields(YourFeatClassOrLayerName,"L*") # List of matching fields, in this case fields starting with L
    fRange = range(len(fList))
    sumNonNull = 0
    # field names into list of string
    fNameList = []
    for f in fList:
        fNameList.append(f.name)

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(YourFeatClassOrLayerName,fNameList,desc.OIDfieldName + " = " + str(YourID)) as sCur:
        for sRow in sCur:
            for thisIndex in fRange:
                if sRow[thisIndex] != None:
                    sumNonNull += 1

    return sumNonNull
```

This script gets a list of matching fields, the OIDfieldName for the feature class (important later) then turns the field list into a list of strings for arcpy.da.SearchCursor - with a query on just one row! then increments if the field is not None (NULL) and returns that. Considering how sloppy it is it's still reasonably fast.

[image]